# How to access custom attribute value of option in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I want to access custom option attribute value but I am failed and I am not able to resolve my problem, could someone please help me to achieve my goal?

**Code**

```
<option value="1" data-set="demo">Value 1</option>
```

I want to access `data-set` value in console how it would be possible please help me?

Comment: How are you trying to access the attribute exactly...?

Comment: actually , I need to access custom attribute @entiendoNull

Comment: In React, you would want to use props instead of using data-* attributes. Could you elaborate your use case?

Comment: @Jonas : there's a surprisingly easy solution of your problem, You might want to check that out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346506/11299053). If it solves your problem upvote and accept are greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: Either you really are talking about React, in which case: your code _generates_ those options, so you already have all those values available to you. Or, you're trying to get attributes from an _HTML element_, having nothing to do with React itself. In that case: you get them the same way we get attributes from any other HTML element. Find the element using any of the query functions (querySelector, getElementById, getElementsByTagName, etc. etc.) and then use `e.getAttribute("blah")` for plain attributes, or `e.dataset.blah` for data attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onChange()` event handler has access to selected options elements (single for regular `<select>`) through `event.target.selectedOptions`

In order to get `data-set` attribute you may leverage [`data-*` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). In a nutshell, it provides access to `data-*` attributes through `.dataset` property of HTMLElement (hence, data-**set** value is accessible via .dataset.**set**):

So, with a bit of destructuring, your task may be solved as easy as that:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const Select = () => {
  const onChangeSelectedOption = ({
    target: {
      selectedOptions: [{
         dataset: {set}
      }]
    }
  }) => console.log(set)
  return (
    <select onChange={onChangeSelectedOption}>
      <option selected disabled>Select...</option>
      <option value="1" data-set="demo1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-set="demo2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-set="demo3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
  )
}

render (
  <Select />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it working but how I will access value like ( e.target.selectedoptions) I mean this way I want to access data-set value

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `handleChange` event on the select, for example with two way binding then you can access it like so:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   console.log( e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-set') );
}
```

In the render it might look like:

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

Comment: `e.target` will point to `<select>` node which doesn't have `data-set` properties at all, so your code will return `undefined`. The proper way to do the job is [a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346506/11299053)

Comment: Good spot! It's simply a case of `e.target.selectedOptions[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const val = document.querySelector("option[value=\"1\"]").getAttribute('data-set')
console.log(val)
```

```html
<option value="1" data-set="demo">Value 1</option>
```

or

```
const val = document.querySelector("option[value=\"1\"]").dataset.set
console.log(val)
```

Comment: what it does `querySelector("option[value=\"1\"]")`

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use `querySelector()` in plain JS or or similar stuff that attempts to access DOM nodes directly, but in React it may give unexpected results due to asynchronous updates of states and corresponding re-renders, so, there's another [*proper*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346506/11299053) way to do that in React

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **onChange** handler function. Then you can get the value of the **data-'format'** easily. You are just required to pass on the **event** parameter. Then we have a **dataset** property using which we can get all the **data-'format'** declared in that tag.  **Dataset** gives back a key value pair object containing custom attribute and its value.

```js
const inputtag=document.getElementById("input_value")

const handleChange=(e)=>{

const customAttributes=e.target.dataset
/*customAttributes containes the attributes you defined, in key value pair*/

console.log(customAttributes)

/* example 
customAttributes = {
  "input": "value1",
  "value": "value2"
}
  

*/
}

inputtag.addEventListener('change',handleChange,true)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id='input_value' data-input='value1' data-value='value2' type='text' placeholder='write here'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, we can get custom attributes data using onClick function too, all the logic will stay as it is.

In case of input tags, we can prefer **onChange** while we can use **onClick** for other tags.